# How to update the value of only one row in custom listview onbuttonclick?

Tags: android

I use productsList.add(p)...by using this the entire listview gets updated with the value of p (where p is an object) ... Instead i want to change only a particular row in listview depending on the position... below is the code fetching data from mysql.....please do help

```
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {

                  JSONArray products = response.getJSONArray("products");

                  for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                  JSONObject product = (JSONObject) products.get(i);

                  String Id = product.getString("id");
                  String name = product.getString("name");                                                              
                  String description = product.getString("description");
                  Double mrp = Double.valueOf(product.getString("mrp"));
                  Double price = Double.valueOf(product.getString("price"));
                  String image = product.getString("image");
                  String sku = product.getString("sku");
                  Product p = new Product(id, name, description, mrp, price, 
                                     image, sku);
                    productsList.add(p);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                    }
              };
```

Comment: r u using recyler view?

Comment: no...im using custom listview which extends ArrayAdapter<Object>

Comment: ArrayAdapter with listview?

Comment: yes...adapter with listview only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter doesn't provide the option to refresh only the specific row. You have to use RecylerView and RecyclerView.Adapter, It will provide an option to update specific row, notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)

You can refer the following link for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33968779/2470770

Answer (score 0):

I think that you not execute the `notifyDataSetChanged();` from the adapter, like this `listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Its like this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427069/calling-notifydatasetchanged-from-inside-adapter-fails